# Can not get latest state in React hook | Stale Closure Issue

Tags: reactjs

I have a React app, there's a `count` increase every second, click on the `button` will alert the latest count after 2 seconds.

- expect: click on the button at 10 seconds, the alert should display 12 (the latest `count` after 2 seconds).
- actual: click on the button at 10 seconds, the alert displays 10 (stale closure issue)

I solved this issue by using "Class component" but I want to understand the Stale closure issue of "Function component".

```js
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setCount(c => c + 1);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  const showCurrentCount = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert(count);
    }, 2000);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => showCurrentCount()}>show</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed my issue by using useRef.

React documentation:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

```js
function App() {
  const refCount = React.useRef();

  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  refCount.current = count;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setCount(c => c + 1);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  const showCurrentCount = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert(refCount.current);
    }, 2000);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <button onClick={showCurrentCount}>show</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the stale value issue by using the callback method of `setState`. Inside the callback, `alert` the `count` return the same `count`.

```
  const showCurrentCount = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setCount((count) => {
         alert(count);
         return count;
      });
    }, 2000);
  };
```

#### Demo

```js
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setCount(c => c + 1);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  const showCurrentCount = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setCount((count) => {
         alert(count);
         return count;
      });
    }, 2000);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => showCurrentCount()}>show</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @Minh Tien, check this out !!

Comment: I try this way at first and it solves the issue. But I'm not sure is it really a right way?

Comment: I also felt like that. But I cannot think of any other way around